# How to recover complex function on $\mathbb C$ from integral equation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function with the form $f(z)= z\tilde{f}(|z|)$ for all $z\in \mathbb C,$ where $\tilde{f}$ is a real function defined on $(0, \infty).$

We define $V:\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ as follows:
$$V(z):=V(|z|), \ \forall z \in \mathbb C;$$
where $V(x)=2\int_{0}^{x} y\tilde{f}(y) dy$ for all $x\geq 0.$

> **My Question**: How to show: $\frac{\partial V (z)}{\partial \bar{z}}= f(z)$ ? (In other words: problem states we can recover $f$ from $V$ by taking partial derivatives with respect to $\bar{z}$ )

Comment: Use the formula for $\bar z$ derivative in terms of polar coordinates. The tangential component is zero, and the result comes out without too much pain.